# Image not shown on vertical-scrollView in a background horizontal-scrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I would like to show let's say 3 long pictures (longer than iPhone's screen height) in a big background `UIScrollView` horizontally, and since each picture is longer than the screen height, so I put another 3 `Sub-UIScrollView` that are for vertical swiping in the background one.

I setup the background one like this:

```
_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
_scrollView.delegate = self;
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth*_count, screenHeight);
_scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
_scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
_scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
```

And I setup each `Sub-UIScrollView` like this:

```
if (imageHeight > screenHeight) { //requiring extra scrollView to support
    UIImageView *longImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [longImgView setFrame:CGRectMake(originX, 0, screenWidth, imageHeight)];
    longImgView.image = _image;
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(originX, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth, imageHeight)];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(originX, 0)];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
    scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
    [scrollView addSubview:longImgView];
    [_scrollView addSubview:scrollView];
}
```

Please notice that I set `scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];` to highlight this `sub-scrollView`, but when I run it, I can only see the blue-colored sub-scrollView, I **cannot** see the picture showing (`longImgView.image = _image;`).

UPDATE: I can see the memory address allocated to the `_image` with break point and console. Also I can see the `sub-scrollView` has set the same `contentSize` as the image size but only cannot see the image itself.

Comment: Make sure the _image doesn't equal nil.

Comment: Ashraf Tawfeeq, they are there, I used break point and console to track the images.

Comment: Give the imageView a different backgroundcolor just to verify it is the added properly. Have you tried another image?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, see what I've done to my imageView: `[longImgView setFrame:CGRectMake(originX, 0, screenWidth, imageHeight)];`, in this case, I surely cannot see the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait: [longImgView setFrame:CGRectMake(originX, 0, screenWidth, imageHeight)];

make that:

[longImgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, imageHeight)];

Comment: Hi tafh, I just realized this...thanks, my stupid mistake.